# Why my element is not staying at the bottom as supposed?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have this layout xml file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/emalLbl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/test" />

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/testTxtLay"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/emalLbl"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/testTxt"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_design" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/reminderLbl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/testTxtLay"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/reminder" />

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/reminderTxtLay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/reminderLbl"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reminderTxt"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:lines="2"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_design" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/spacer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/reminderTxtLay"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/pickDateBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/reminderTxtLay"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spacer"
            android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
            android:text="@string/datePickerBtnTxt" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pickTimeBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/pickDateBtn"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pickDateBtn"
            android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog"
            android:text="@string/pickTimeBtn" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/spacerTxt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/reminderTxtLay"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/selectedDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/spacerTxt"
            android:layout_below="@id/pickDateBtn"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spacerTxt" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/selectedTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/selectedDate"
            android:layout_below="@id/pickTimeBtn"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/selectedDate" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:onClick="submitData"
            android:text="@string/submitBtn" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the custom design for 7 inch tablets, placed in `res\layout-sw600dp`

Anyways in the android studio landscape preview it seems just fine:

[image]

But in the emulator something is going wrong and here is how it looks strange. What I mean is that the submit button is not on the bottom and the `pickDate` and `pickTime` buttons are at the bottom of the layout.

[image]
[image]

I know that I'm missing a basic point here, but as an android developer, I'm not able to spot it.

Can you give me a push?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the center in parent on the submit button?

Comment: @karaokyo to center it

Comment: If you want to center it vertically, it can't be aligned to parent bottom. If you want to center it horizontally, it's already matching parent width.

Comment: You should be using linear layouts

Comment: always use LinearLayout inside ScrollView instead of Relative layout .if  you want submit button  to align buttom of screen use RelativeLayout as a rootview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete way to do what you seem to try accomplish. You don't need to create any Views for "spaces" etc. You only need to add margin or padding to either side of your views to make it move away from another view.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/emalLbl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/test" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/testTxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_design" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/reminderLbl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/reminder" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reminderTxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="2"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_design" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pickDateBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
                android:text="@string/datePickerBtnTxt" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pickTimeBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog"
                android:text="@string/pickTimeBtn" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/selectedDate"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/selectedTime"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_wrapper"
        android:onClick="submitData"
        android:text="@string/submitBtn" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That way `selectedDate` and `selectedTime` are hidden under the submit button.

Comment: You are right, forgot to add a below on the submit button. Its edited now.

You could also just put the submitbutton inside the outer LinearLayout in the bottom and it will always be at the bottom of all the views, but not necessarily at the bottom of the screen. All depending on your screen size.

Comment: But now it's gone when it's not in landscape mode. :(

Comment: Really? Looks good for me. It wont show up if you scroll down?

Comment: Yep,  its not there.  Just missing

Answer (score 0):

you can place 2 buttons next to each other!

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```